# How to convert a strongname public key (snk) to <RSAKeyValue>?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, strongname, snk

I have a file testpublic.snk which holds a public key. I have created it with sn -p c:\test.snk c:\testpublic.snk.
Now, how can I convert testpublic.snk to a string like

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>z140GwiEJvuGOVqMQUxnojILR8rn2SFOViigoloku59H5eqzqca3Hdyl/jc+Acdb5ktzhBOOyGFElE0/Btlvw9cXVVW8zcT0MBOCaq25D1rSVYLGGM6nXzBrl1XsrBEadZbCgkcF5rw8GaYcYakijaltP1/hvxhbMOARM9VCQ50=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know about snk.exe but I think the RsaCryptoProvider has some ways to get the (public) as XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply re-use the (MIT.X11 licensed) code from [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com).Security [StrongName](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security/StrongName.cs) class, available in github, then call [ToXmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on it's RSA property. Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine (new StrongName (data).RSA.ToXmlString (false));
```

Where **data** is a byte[] containing the content of your **snk** file. Also you can use **true** if you want the private key in your XML (it will work if it was available fom your **snk** file).